# AsyncTask, doInBackground doesn't seem to work

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have that AsyncTask code

```
public class DiceTask extends AsyncTask<Socket, Void, int[]> {

private int[] arrayFromServer = new int[8];

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected int[] doInBackground(Socket...params) {
    Socket soc = params[0];

    try {
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
        int[] tempArray = (int[]) (ois.readObject());
        return tempArray;
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void...arg1) {

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(int[] result) {
    arrayFromServer = result;

}

public int[] getTempDice() {
    return arrayFromServer;
}
}
```

where is called this way into my main thread.

```
rollDiceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            rollDiceButton.setEnabled(false);
            rollDice();
            task.execute(socket);
            tempArray = task.getTempDice();
            printDice(tempArray,pDice);
            clickableDice(pDice);
        }
    });
```

where I am getting a `null tempArray`. If I change my `onPreExecute` to this

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayFromServer.length; i++) {
        arrayFromServer[i] = 1;
    }
}
```

I am getting my dice as it should, all are one. The code I am running into the `rollDice()` is this

```
public void rollDice() {

    try {
        DataOutputStream sout = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        String line = "dice";
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(sout);
        out.println(line);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

and I can see the results in the server.

Comment: I do not think your result is available just after calling execute. You may want to add a callback/listener to your AsyncTask. Additionally, AsyncTasks are not reusable. You can call the '.execute' method only once on each AsyncTask instance.

Comment: @tato.rodrigo yeah I know that I need more instances for each call but I am trying to make that one work, and I will figure something out. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to implement `onPostExecute` in your AsyncTask class definition.  You also don't need the `getTempDice` function.  You just need to override `onPostExecute` in an anonymous class and run your UI code in it.

```
rollDiceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        rollDiceButton.setEnabled(false);
        rollDice();
        task = new DiceTask() {
            @Override
            public void onPostExecute(int[] result) {
                tempArray = result;
                printDice(tempArray,pDice);
                clickableDice(pDice);
            }
        }.execute(socket);
    }
});
```

Comment: It works and it's 100% understandable. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Children of `AsyncTask` run in parallel  with main `Thread`, you are trying access the attribute `arrayFromServer` right after to start the `Thread`. It's recommended you use a callback to retried the value wanted, making sure you get the value after `Thread` is done.

Making the follow changes can solve your problem. Let me know if you understand.

```
public class DiceTask extends AsyncTask<Socket, Void, int[]> {

    public interface Callback {
        void onDone(int[] arrayFromServer);
    }

    private Callback mCallback;

    public DiceTask(Callback c) {
        mCallback = c;
    }

    @Override
    protected int[] doInBackground(Socket...params) {
        Socket soc = params[0];

        try {
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
            int[] tempArray = (int[]) (ois.readObject());
            return tempArray;
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(int[] result) {
        mCallback.onDone(result);
    }

}




rollDiceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        rollDiceButton.setEnabled(false);
        rollDice();
        new DiceTask(new Callback() {
             public void onDone(int[] tempArray) {
                  printDice(tempArray,pDice);
                  clickableDice(pDice);
             }
        }).execute(socket);

    }
});
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged here on SO. While they might solve the problem it is more important to state what the problem was.

Comment: This is true but if it is an inner-class of the `Activity` then the code to run after the task finishes can also be put in `onPostExecute()` then a callback really isn't needed.

Comment: It's right, now you need chose the better approach for you.

Comment: @betorcs well first thanks for your answer. The truth is that I cannot understand what are you doing here `static class Callback { void onDone(int[] arrayFromServer);}` because even the compiler says it is something wrong. Something is missing I think.